# how can we split a column value based on nth character and shift the remaining of characters in next column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, split

```
RECORDID               ELEMENT  ID  NUM  
207ejhgyyhfh1101100111 RIDF     TNT 1899114676  
207ejh56yhfh1201100111 ISTA     FITE2208675367
```

I want to split the RECORDID column value so that first 2 characters comes into  column RECORDID, next 10 characters comes into column ELEMENT, next 4 characters comes into column ID and so on. My output should look like as given below:

```
RECORDID       ELEMENT       ID   NUM  
20             7ejhgyyhfh    1101 100111  
20             7ejh56yhfh    1201 100111
```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert a string into a list and then expand it into columns

First we load the df (assume you already have it but for reproducibility of the solution)

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
data = StringIO(
"""
RECORDID               ELEMENT  ID  NUM  
207ejhgyyhfh1101100111 RIDF     TNT 1899114676  
207ejh56yhfh1201100111 ISTA     FITE 2208675367
""")
df = pd.read_csv(data, delim_whitespace=True)
```

Then

```
(df['RECORDID'].apply(lambda s:[s[0:2],s[2:12], s[12:16], s[16:22]])
               .apply(pd.Series)
               .rename(columns = {0:'RECORDID',1:'ELEMENT',2:'ID', 3:'NUM'})
               )
```

produces

```
    RECORDID    ELEMENT     ID      NUM
0   20          7ejhgyyhfh  1101    100111
1   20          7ejh56yhfh  1201    100111
```

Comment: Thanks piterbarg. But doing that will replace the value of what I have in column ELEMENT, ID and NUM. I want value of those column shift to next column.

Comment: the code produces the output as you specified. if this is not the output you desire, please update that

Comment: Thanks @piterbarg. Posting my question again for my detailed clarification.

Comment: @sac you should edit your question and put your formatted output there

Comment: @piterbarg...I have posted the detailed query again. Please follow this link [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66470969/splitting-the-column-value-and-and-shift-the-values-of-other-columns-to-the-righ